# Как пересылать сообщения, отправленные пользователем боту и содержащие определенные символы, другому пользователю

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot, telethon

Вопрос в следующем: есть бот, человек в него пишет номер заявки в тех поддержку, указывая номер заявки и краткое название ГИС, например, "ЭБ, 1654356" или "КИ, 44566".

Как сделать, чтобы бот пересылал сообщения по одному условию ("ЭБ, 1654356") одному выбранному пользователю, а по другому условию ("КИ, 44566") другому выбранному пользователю?

Я нашел такие варианты на telebot и telethon, но что-то не работает ((

```
from telebot import TeleBot


bot = TeleBot('[token]')  # Не забудьте подставить свой токен!
TO_CHAT_ID = ...          # Не забудьте подставить нужный id!


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def all_messages(message):
    bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID, message.chat.id, message.message_id)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

И вот такой еще вариант для удаления сообщений, содержащих условие, но не для пересылки

```
 @client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern=r'(?i).*heck')) 
 async def handler(event):
    await event.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй bot.forward_message()

Пример:

```
import psycopg2

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token=TOKEN, parse_mode="MARKDOWN")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def message(msg):
    if msg.text == "ЭБ, 1654356":  # Условые пересылки сообщения
        bot.forward_message(
            chat_id=1093110311,  # chat_id чата в которое необходимо переслать сообщение
            from_chat_id=msg.chat.id,  # chat_id из которого необходимо переслать сообщение
            message_id=msg.message_id  # message_id которое необходимо переслать
        )
    elif msg.text == "КИ, 44566":  #Пересылка при другом условии.
        bot.forward_message(
            chat_id=1093110311,  # chat_id чата в которое необходимо переслать сообщение
            from_chat_id=msg.chat.id,  # chat_id из которого необходимо переслать сообщение
            message_id=msg.message_id  # message_id которое необходимо переслать
        )
```

[image: Результат]

Comment: Благодарю! Я хотел бы уточнить, как с помощью Regex научить бот распознавать, какие символы в сообщении, и таким образом чтобы пересылались сообщения нужному пользователю? 

Паттерн готов вроде как, как его использовать?

`pattern = re.compile(r'(?i).\d+.+эб')`

Comment: `pattern.match(text)` вернет `None` если не найдет символы из pattern в text, в противном случае возвращает класс. Можете посмотреть сами, `print(pattern.match(text))`.
[Сдесь вроде подробно написано](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)